# What would be the equivalent of an array in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table that needs each row to store an ordered collection of rows of the same type.

e.g., I am imagining something similar to:

```
class blah
{
   float yetMoreData;
};

class foo
{
   int data;
   String moreData;
   blah[] anOrderedCollectionOfBlahClasses;
};
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `Blah` and `Foo` to be separate tables, where `Blah` has a many-to-one relationship with `Foo`.  The records in the `Blah` table should have a foreign key `foo_id`, identifying their parent Foo record.  `Blah` also has an `index_in_array` attribute that allows the results to be sorted.

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    id BIGINT,
    data INT,
    moreData CHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Blah (
    id BIGINT,
    yetMoreData DOUBLE,
    foo_id BIGINT,
    index_in_array INT
);
```

If you want to get all the `Blah`s of a given `Foo` (say, the `Foo` with the ID of 5), use:

```
SELECT * FROM Blah
WHERE Blah.foo_id = 5
ORDER BY Blah.index_in_array;
```

If you're ordering records, usually it shouldn't be by something arbitrary (unless that arbitrary order was chosen specifically by the user, e.g., sorting the items on a to-do list).  Normally, you sort on some "naturally-occurring" property of the data, like the date it was added or alphabetically by name, etc.

N.B.: This answer is meant to be pseudocode SQL -- make sure you adapt it to your specific database syntax before you toss it into a script.  (And don't forget to add some keys and indexes!)

Comment: Seems somewhat backwards from what I am used to, the elements refer to their main class instead of the opposite way around, but I guess it makes sense in a strange sort of way.

Answer (score 1):

Databases don't usually store things in a certain order. You can retrieve things from a database ordered in multiple ways. For example, say you had a table calendar:

```
CREATE TABLE month AS (
    id      NUMBER,
    month   NUMBER,
    day     NUMBER 
);
```

You could then retrieve the days of the year in order:

```
SELECT month, day
  FROM calendar
 ORDER BY month, day;
```

That being said, there are ways to do what you're asking. Oracle, for example can store nested tables.

Answer (score 0):

You create two table and create Primary Key and Foreign Key relationship between them. It will be treated as nested tables and per your nested objects.